# how get the date and time of the last modified particular TYPE file in that directory in c#

Tags: c#

how get the date and time of the last modified particular TYPE file in that directory

let me explain with an example

there are many files in directory say y:\tempfiles now i want to get the date and time of last modified file of txt format files like

```
9-03-2010 11.35 arun.reo 
9-03-2010 11.31 arun1.reo 
9-03-2010 11.31 arun.txt 
9-03-2010 11.31 arun.avi
```

now i want the out put as 9-03-2010 11.35 which is last modified file for reo type files .

Answer (score 4):

```
var lastWrite = Directory.GetFiles(@"y:\tempfiles", "*.reo")
                         .Select(filename => File.GetLastWriteTime(filename))
                         .Max();
Console.WriteLine(lastWrite);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Directory.GetFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to get all the txt files in the specified folder. Than you can use [File.GetLastWriteTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx)  to get the desired date.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate LINQ version that I suspect will perform better than tzaman's, due to getting all the `FileInfo` entries at once, rather than doing a separate filesystem call for each filename:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp");
DateTime lastModified = di.GetFiles("*.dll")
                          .Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.LastWriteTime)
                          .Max();
Console.WriteLine(lastModified.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm"));
```